# Deploying and SQL Server 2005 Express connecting for a standard user

Tags: sql, delphi, sql-server-2005-express, installaware

I have tried days to find solution maybe simple problem as newbie with SQL. A program is coded using SQL Server 2005 Express and for installing is used InstallAware Express, which was included with Delphi X package. Deploying and using later on program goes fine with XP and Win 7 as long if you are an administrator user. But if you want to change as standard User, program does not find databases.

I have tried to add in IA Server Configuration/SQL Databases/SQL Script window new lines at different places among data script lines as follows:

```
GRANT CONNECT TO user
GO
```

But if I use Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Express program, go to Databases, to some own database, click Security, then open Users, double click Users icon and in the Role Members window click active `db_datareader`, `db_writer` and `db_ddadmin`, everything works fine even for standard user.

Is there even in principle possible to make this task automatically during installation with IA Express?  Is there alternative installing software who can do this job?

Answer (score 0):

My aim was to do software ready installation with SQL available for everyone standard Users.  Finally, I used MS Database Publishing Wizard 1.1 and not Server Management Studio Express 2005 or 2012 to make scripts for databases with data and schema for repository data.  Solution for deploying at different platforms was by adding the following lines at the beginning of scripts:

```
CREATE USER [Users] FOR LOGIN [BUILTIN\Users]
GO
exec sp_addrolemember db_datareader, Users 
go
exec sp_addrolemember db_datawriter, Users 
go
```